# How can i select 2 icons for single item in a tab bar?

Tags: ios7, icons, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBarController and i'm setting icons but i can not select the unselected icons successful. It seams i just select one 1 icon and a selected colour and that's it.

How can i pic a colour or set a separate icon for the not selected state?
I'm setting the icon and selected icon with no success.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Set the status bar to light style
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"TabBar"];
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

    NSLog(@"%@", tabBar.items);

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    //UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    //UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

    tabBarItem1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconTabBarFolder"];
    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconTabBarFolder:Highlighted"];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:10.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add images for `UITabbarItem` by using this code:

```
 [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stores222.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-icon-inactive.png"]];
```

Update for iOS7:
please use this code :

```
    UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a"]; 
    aImage = [aImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    UIImage *inaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ina"];
    inaImage = [inaImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    self.aController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" image:inaImage selectedImage:aImage];
```

Comment: It is a bad practise to use deprecated methods.